# Apache proxy base url match

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy

My requirement is to match the URL in domain level, could you please tell me what exactly I have to do for this.

If the user browses to x.y.example.com or y.z.example.com, then when they reach the Apache proxy, it needs to resolve to the same name and open the page.

What I have done now is added each url individually like below but I want domain level which will make my life easy

Current config

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.0.1:80>
        ServerName x.y.example.com
        ServerAlias x.y.example.com
        ProxyPreserveHost Off
        ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*[.](svc))$ http://x.y.example.com/$1
        ProxyPassReverse ^/(.*[.](svc))$  http://x.y.example.com/$1
        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/test_error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

I am looking for

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.0.1:80>
        ServerName *.*.example.com
        ServerAlias *.*.example.com
        ProxyPreserveHost Off
        ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*[.](svc))$ http://*.*.example.com/$1
        ProxyPassReverse ^/(.*[.](svc))$  http://*.*.example.com/$1
        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/test_error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Whatever servername or serveralias is used, it should proxypass to same URL. Please point me to exact solution, last two days I googled all but couldn't get exact solution anywhere.

Comment: Hi Guys, Is there no answer for this , I am keenly looking for an answer.

Comment: Still waiting for an answer, is it possible with rewrite rule or anything?